# dnsextd connection to server error

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, launchd

How can I correct these dnsextd errors in my system error log? dnsextd keeps starting and restarting via lanchd. Can I disable dnsextd via command line?

dnsextd ConnectToServer: connect - Socket is not connected

dnsextd ConnectToServer - retrying connection